# Updating user profile picture in liferay for role other than super admin

Tags: java, content-management-system, liferay, admin, profile

I am trying to create a role in liferay and have given almost all the permissions. But a user with that role is not able to see the upload button for changing profile picture. What is the exact permission that I need to set ?

Answer (score 0):

No need any specific permission of **Role**, by which user can change Profile picture.